# designing a backend with an mvc framework in php

Tags: php

I do not know how to design a backend for my application. Of course I can always just create simple CRUD operations but I recently ran into the concept of scaffolding and some more "techniques" for your backend to be matched against your database schema.

Any ideas on how I can use this "scaffolding" and other "backend design techniques"?

of course I'm assuming that we're using an MVC framewoek here(I am using the PHP framework Kohana at version 2.3.4)

So here's a better question : Are there frameworks or guidelines for creating backend CMS in mvc frameworks (for production, that is)?

I recently saw Django's backend interface...anything similar from any of the PHP frameworks?

Comment: Are you asking how to scaffold in Kohana? I don't understand your question. The only real difference between 'normal design techniques' and backend ones are authentication schemes. Could you be more specific?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scaffolding is a technique or a functionality often provided by modern MVC frameworks like CakePHP and ZendFramework which allows developers to quickly come up with a temporary platform where they can build their app on top of.

This usually means writing the minimal amount of code to come up with CRUD functionality.

For example in CakePHP, you only have to write the following code and *wallah!*

```
<?php

class FooController extends AppController {
    var $scaffold;
}

?>
```

However, note that scaffolds should only be **temporary** and you should replace them with actual CRUD screens especially when your app goes to production.

Based on what I know, Kohana doesn't natively support scaffolding.  However there are modules that will allow such functionality.  I haven't used any of the following but they might give you some ideas.

[Scaffolding module for Kohana PHP](http://projects.kohanausers.org/scaffolding)

[John Heathco's scaffolding module](http://mhordecki.wordpress.com/2008/02/07/scaffolding-module-for-kohana-php/)

Comment: Nothing says modern like PHP 4! :P